# How to calculate the accumulated sum over a certain threshold?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of daily temperature measurements and want to calculate the accumulated sum of temperatures over 32°C. I don't want to know in how many days the temperature exceeds 32 `sum(tmax_mean > 32)`, but accumulate the temperature values over 32. So, if temperature was 31,33,34,..., the code should calculate 0+1+2+...

```
tmax_mean <- c(31.3,32.1,33.5,29,34.2)
```

I've tried    `sum(tmax_mean > 32)`    but that only tells me the number of days where temperature exceeds 32°C, which is 3 in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may use

```
sum((tmax_mean - 32)[tmax_mean > 32])
# [1] 3.8
```

Here `tmax_mean > 32` helps to subset needed terms, while `tmax_mean - 32`, in those cases, are our summands.

---

Also,

```
sum((tmax_mean - 32) * (tmax_mean > 32))
# [1] 3.8
```

using the same logic and the fact that `number * TRUE` is `number` and `number * FALSE` is `0`:

```
3 * TRUE
# [1] 3
3 * FALSE
# [1] 0
```

---

In the same way, using matrix multiplication `%*%` (since both `tmax_mean - 32` and `tmax_mean > 32` can be seen as vectors),

```
(tmax_mean - 32) %*% (tmax_mean > 32)
#      [,1]
# [1,]  3.8
```

which is now a 1x1 matrix, which may or may not be acceptable in your case.

Comment: ... and another alt `sum(pmax(tmax_mean - 32, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

#### With base R

```
sum(subset(tmax_mean, tmax_mean > 32) - 32)
```